# Code blocks crashing on compilation

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks

I just installed GNU GCC Compiler. Then I configured it in Code Blocks:

[image]

But when I try to compile and run the simplest hello world program any IDE I try to use crashes:

[image]

I think everything is in place in the folder MinGW\bin where the compiler's exe files are supposed to be:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you create your hello world project?

Comment: Report a bug to Code::Block maintainers. Meanwhile, try reinstalling it, and if it doesn't help, reinstalling your OS.

Comment: Maybe you have a dll conflict.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I clicked "create new project" and then created a console application

Comment: Perhaps mingw installed dlls that are incompatible with the dlls required for Code::Blocks.

Comment: @drescherjm what should I do then?

Comment: OK, that looks right. Are you sure you can write to the directory you created the project in - in other words, did you create it under /Users/Yourname? Also, you should look at using the TDM GCC implementation that one of the codeblocks downloads comes with. I would uninstall, and reinstall that one.

Comment: I would try uninstalling Code::Blocks and mingw. And then install the Code::Blocks that comes bundled with mingw.

Comment: @drescherjm It didn't work. I uninstalled Code::Blocks and mingw and installed codeblocks-16.01mingw-setup.exe but the problem remains

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yes I created it under /Users/Myname but it didn't help

Comment: I suspect you are left with 3 options: 1. Reinstall Your OS, 2. Install a different IDE (like QtCreator if you want to keep mingw or Visual Studio 2015 community) or 3. Report this as a bug to Code::Blocks and wait for them to figure out the problem. I guess a 4th option is to try this on a different computer.